# Asymptotic behaviour of order statistic $x_{(n-k+1)}$ when k is $n^{\alpha}$

Tags: probability, asymptotics, order-statistics

I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of the top k-th order statistic
$x_{(n-k+1)}$ from n i.i.d. standard normal samples, when k is $n^\alpha$ where $\alpha\in (0,1)$.
I just wonder if we can lower bound the order of the limit of $x_{(n-k+1)}$, for 
example, if the n i.i.d samples come from standard normal distribution, can we say that the order of $x_{(n-k+1)}$ is higher than something like $(\log(n))^{1/4}$ as n goes to infinity?